# É certo dizer que amanhã é ou foi um lindo dia?

Tags: gramática

É certo dizer que amanhã é um lindo dia, como é certo dizer que o futuro foi um lindo tempo da história?

É certo dizer que o futuro do presente foi ou é lindo, como é certo dizer que o futuro do passado foi ou é lindo?

Comment: Em “amanhã é um lindo dia”, estamos tratando “amanhã” como substantivo masculino ou como advérbio, deste falarei depois; em “amanhã será um lindo dia”, estamos tratando “amanhã” como advérbio ou como substantivo, i.e., tanto “o amanhã será um dia lindo” quanto “no dia de amanhã, será um dia lindo” funcionam. Em português, podemos usar o tempo presente em vez do tempo futuro; ex.: “em 2571, sou rico, mas hoje, em 2021, estou no vermelho”.

Comment: Renanlinux, desculpa, mas não *capisco* o segundo parágrafo.

Comment: Eu fiquei muito curioso com o 2º parágrafo. Em qual contexto, por exemplo, alguém falaria que o futuro do passado foi (é ou será) lindo?

Comment: O futuro do passado pode ser o hoje, ou o ontem, ou a semana passada, etc. Se esse futuro foi ontem, por exemplo, dá para se dizer que foi lindo e que é um lindo futuro do passado na história. Se esse futuro for hoje, podemos dizer que ele é lindo, e até mesmo que foi lindo caso tenha acontecido, por exemplo, uma hora atrás.

Comment: Renanlinux, sabes que a frase não precisa ser lógica ou fazer sentido para ser gramatical? Pois é o caso.

Answer (score -2):

Não, não é correto.
"Amanhã" é sempre futuro. "AMANHÃ SERÁ UM DIA LINDO" (isso desconsiderando o talvez....rs)
Mas também temos mais "tipos de futuro".  Alguns exemplos - não todos;

INDICATIVO:

1. Futuro do presente do indicativo é o mais usual e responde sua pergunta: "AMANHÃ SERÁ UM DIA LINDO
2. Futuro do pretérito do indicativo: "AMANHÃ SERIA UM DIA LINDO"

SUBJUNTIVO:

3. Futuro do pretérito do subjuntivo: "AMANHÃ PODERÁ SER UM DIA LINDO"

Em uma história, o mais correto a dizer é "o dia seguinte foi lindo" - mais social - ou "o dia subsequente àquele foi lindo", de uma forma mais social.
Quando se refere ao passado, são situações já ocorridas, portanto você dizer simplesmente "ontem foi um dia lindo". Já aconteceu...nas veja acima algumas opções de futuro e pretérito juntos.

Comment: Julia, neste site tentamos trabalhar com referências. Estando a tua resposta certa ou errada, ela tem a mesma força desta resposta "'amanhã' não existe, logo 'amanhã será um bom dia' está errado".

Comment: O amanhã de anteontem, sendo ontem, não é o futuro, exceto o futuro de anteontem ou de antes de anteontem.